# Trendy Latex resume

Tags: cv

is there any Latex script to compile such resume?
http://ginva.com/2012/07/25-modern-and-professional-resume-templates/
Cheers,
No mans land

Comment: http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/curricula-vitae

Comment: I guess there is no *Latex script to compile such resume*, but, of course, it's possible to create *such kind of resumes* in Latex.

Comment: What kind of employer wants to read these kinds of resumes..?  Although I guess this is the [new trend](http://xkcd.com/1273/)...

Comment: @jon that page says "... if you are a graphic designer".

Comment: @Guido -- Well, I suppose they'd be the ones responsible for a trend in tall infographics.  (Admittedly, some are better than others, but many designs on that page obfuscate important information rather than present it: just because some information can be put in a pie chart doesn't mean it is helpful to do so.) ... Then again: I'm not in a position to hire any graphic designers, good or bad.

Comment: The formatting for those documents can certainly be achieved using LaTeX. Are you interested in one in particular?